# How does Quantum GIS work with ArcGIS XML files?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.1, xml, import

I'm not familiar to Quantum GIS, so can anyone explain if it is possible to import/export XML files in Quantum GIS? If it is possible, how can I do that?

I exported some `xml` recordset and workspace files from ArcGIS and I'm curios if I can open those files in Quantum GIS.

I use ArcGIS 10.1 and Quantum GIS 1.8.0

Comment: i'm interested in importing in qgis .xml files created in arcgis that contain records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArcGIS XML is not a valid data source for QGIS and so you can't import or export it. KML, a variety of XML, is. My thought is to use Python to parse your XML into KML(s) files. QGIS GDAL/OGR could convert that to whatever you like, for instance Spatialite or PostGIS.

Comment: Sorry for the slow persons question on an answer, but i have no exp in Python or PostGIS or Spatilite....is there a pluggin to convert it in QGIS